# What does "Bonus time is just around the corner" mean?

Tags: dialogue, the-truman-show

Here's a little bit of context from the movie *The Truman Show*:

> Marlon: Whew. So when are you gonna go?
>
> Truman: It’s not that simple. It takes money, planning. Can’t just up
> and go.
>
> Marlon: Right.
>
> Truman: I’m gonna do it. Don’t worry about that. **Bonus time is just
> around the corner**.

I don't know if I can understand the meaning of **Bonus time is just around the corner** here. Does the bonus time relate to the game of golf (Truman and Marlon are playing golf while having a conversation), or it just means some extra time? *Just around the corner* means that something is not far away or going to happen soon. But where is the connection here? I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Bonus time

... is the time of year where bonuses (from your employer, on top of your usual salary) are paid out.

> ...  is just around the corner

means that it is going to happen in the near future.

In context:

> It’s not that simple. **It takes money**, planning. Can’t just up and go. I’m gonna do it. Don’t worry about that. Bonus time is just around the corner.

Truman is saying that there's no financial reason for him to not go on holiday, just that he can't go on holiday *right now*. Once he gets his bonus, he'll have the money needed to go on holiday.

Answer (score 5):

Truman is an insurance salesman. Since all of his sales are fake, this gives the makers of the show the ability to [stress him](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=zRpny-GEBi8) (when needed) but also to reward him with small victories when they want him to be in a good mood, and provide him with finances to buy the products they're advertising.

It would appear that in addition to his normal salary and a small commission on each sale, he also receives an annual ['bonus payment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonus_payment)' from the company, presumably based on their putative performance. In both versions of the script ([1](https://www.scriptslug.com/script/the-truman-show-1998), [2](https://www.sellingyourscreenplay.com/wp-content/uploads/screenplay/scripts/The-Truman-Show.pdf)) he states to Marlon that he intends to use this money to finish off some renovations to the house, sell up and then travel to Fiji.

> **TRUMAN:** [...] *Oh, I'm going to do it, don't worry about that. I've just got to move slow. Pick my moment. Bonus time's just around the corner. Soon as I finish the...*
>
> **MARLON:** *Nursery?*
>
> **TRUMAN:** *Spare room - I can start thinking about selling up...and I'll be gone. Up and away on that big steel bird.*

The makers of the show are repeatedly telling Truman that the company isn't doing well financially (e.g. that his bonus will be smaller than normal this year), which is presumably going to have a knock-on effect to his plans to leave Seahaven.

> **LAWRENCE:** You'll lose a lot more than your teeth if you don't meet your quota, Burbank.(the threat in his voice is unmistakable) They're making cutbacks at the end of the month. You need this.

The bonus, and Truman's job in general, is yet another form of control. By providing him with regular 'wins', Kristoff can influence Truman's mood and conversely, exert financial control over him by providing him with stressors.